# How to prevent Adobe Acrobat Reader opening PDF files in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, pdf, adobe-reader

I'm using PDFXchange Viewer to open PDF files, because it's much faster compared to Adobe Reader and I like the rendering better. I had to install Adobe Reader for testing purposes, and now Firefox opens every PDF document with the ultra-slow Adobe Reader. In the settings of Firefox, it still says that PDFXchange is used to open PDFs, but this is not the case.

How can I get rid of the Adobe Reader opening PDFs directly in Firefox without uninstalling something?

Comment: Have you tried disabling the plugin as per the instructions here: http://kb.mozillazine.org/Adobe_Reader#Disabling_the_browser_plugin ?

Comment: Options > Applications > PDF -> Choose plugin.

Answer (score 3):

Go into the Add-ons Manager and select the Plugins tab. From here you can disable any installed plugins, like Acrobat, Flash, Silverlight, Java, etc.

[image]